# Showing a space similar to the topologist's sine curve is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

> Let $A_n = \{1/n\} \times [-n,n]$, when $n \in \Bbb N$. Show that the subset $$X=\Bbb R^2 \setminus \left( \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n \right)$$ is connected.

Usually these connectedness problems are solved by showing path-connectedness or assuming the contrary. In this case I'm quite sure the space isn't path-connected as there is no way to get a path to the origin from any point $(x,y)$ when $x >0$.

Assuming the contrary that $X = A \cup B$ where $A , B$ are closed in $\Bbb R^2$ and $A \cap B= \emptyset$. I should be able to figure out to find a contradiction from here, but I don't see it. This reminds me of the topologist's sine curve as the slices will start to oscillate very quickly near the origin, but I cannot get any data to work form these "slices". My idea was to assume wlog that the origin is in $A$ and then try to find something useful from there, but I don't now what conclusions I can draw from here. May I have some hints on what to consider?

Comment: I think you need $X \subset A \cup B$, not $X = A \cup B$. $X$ itself is not open.

Comment: If $(0,0) \in A$ then $\exists \epsilon > 0: |x|<\epsilon \implies x \in A$, so $\exists y>0$ such that $\{0\} \times [-y,y] \subset A$ and $1/y \notin \mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @aschepler I meant closed sets!

Comment: What's your definition of connected then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X^+=\{(x,y)\in X:x>0\}$ and $X^-=\{(x,y)\in X:x<0\}$ and $X^0=\{0\}\times\Bbb R.$

Suppose $C,D$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$ with $C\cup D=X.$ Now each of $X^+,X^-, X^0$ is a connected subspace of $X$ so each of them is a subset of $C$ or a subset of $D.$ So WLOG let $X^0\subset C.$ But an open set that covers $X^0$ cannot be disjoint from $X^+$ nor disjoint from $X^-.$ So neither $X^+$ nor $X^-$ can be a subset of $D.$

Your suspicion that $X$ is not path-connected is correct.

Comment: How do you conclude that each of $X^+,X^-, X^0$ are connected subspaces? @danielwainfleet

Comment: If $(x,y),(x',y')\in X^+$ with $x\le x',$ take $d>0$ where $d$ is small enough that each of $(x,x+d], (x',x'+d]$ is disjoint from $\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}.$ Then take $z>0$ large enough that $no$ member of the finite set $\{n\in\Bbb N: 1/n\in [x,x'+d]\}$ is equal to or greater than $z.$ Consider the path in $X^+$ made of line-segments $AB, BC, CD, DE, EF$ where $A=(x,y), B=(x+d,y), C=(x+d,z), D=(x'+d,z), E=(x'+d,y'), F=(x',y').$ .... $X^0$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ .... $X^-=(-\infty,0)\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: I noticed a different method, using the results that (1) If $Y$ is a connected subspace of any space $X$ then $\overline Y$ is connected, and (2) if $Z_1,Z_2$ are connected subspaces of any space $X$ and $Z_1\cap Z_2\ne\emptyset$ then $Z_1\cup Z_2$ is connected. In the notation of my Answer, let $Y_1=X^-,$ $ Y_2=X^+,$ $ Z_1=\overline {Y_1},$ $ Z_2=\overline {Y_2}$ ( closures in the space $X$).- Observe that $\emptyset\ne X^0=Z_1\cap Z_2$ and $Z_1\cup Z_2=X.$

Comment: Can you just consider $X^-=\{(x,y)\in X:x \le 0\}$ and $X^+=\{(x,y)\in X:x>0\}$ without having $X^0$ at all?

Comment: Yes. Good one.................